# Custom valueOf for a function in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a simple utility function that multiplies any amount of numbers in currying way. Also I've set valueOf for internal function, so now console(mult(10)(3)(2) should display "60". But what it displays in reality is "function 60". Is this an incorrect way to use it? Or valueOf is not intended to work with functions?

Here is the code:

```
var mult = function (y) {
    var that = this;
    that.x = y;
    that.f = function(s) {
        that.x = that.x * s;
        return that.f;
    }
    that.f.valueOf = function (){return that.x;};
    return that.f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of adding the `valueOf` function is to force evaluation of the final function. You can either call it explicitly

```
console.log(mult(10)(3)(2).valueOf());
```

Or prepend a `+`

```
console.log(+mult(10)(3)(2));
```

```js
var mult = function (y) {
    var that = this;
    that.x = y;
    that.f = function(s) {
        that.x = that.x * s;
        return that.f;
    }
    that.f.valueOf = function (){return that.x;};
    return that.f;
}
console.log(mult(10)(3)(2))
console.log(mult(10)(3)(2).valueOf())
console.log(+mult(10)(3)(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call valueOf() in your console.log statement to force the evaluation:

```
console.log(mult(10)(3)(2).valueOf());
// 60
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qomovnj/)