# In JS can you assign getter, and function call for same property?

Tags: javascript

Can this be done...

```
a; // 1

a(); // function call
```

Different way to ask question would be is there getter for parenthesis.

hello haters....

I've learned that it's INDEED possible, although not as asked

```
function a() {
  console.log('hi im in a function')
}

a.valueOf = function() {
  return 1;
}

a == 1; // > true

a(); // > "hi im in a function"
```

But I wont use it in my code and will not work with anyone who writes code like this either.

Comment: Note that the actual value of `a` is not 1 (`a === 1` is false), only that 1 is used when the function is being cast to another type. (This in contrast to a real getter that does have the actual value.)

Comment: yes, which further makes it terrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. A value is either a number or a function, it can't be both. There is no operator overloading that would allow you to give arbitrary values the ability to be called.

(You can however create a function object with a `valueOf` method that allows the object to be treated like a number in certain contexts, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45163389/1048572) for an example).